# How to write the expression a<=20?b=30:c=30; such that 30 is used only once?

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

I'm following a book on c programming and encountered this example:

```
a<=20?b=30:c=30;
```

I just have to use the number 30 one time. The solution in the book was

```
((a<=20)?&b:&c)=30);
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

It seems like one of the parenthesis is missing there, but I don't know where.

Can you please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: this looks like a pointless exercise

Comment: `*((a<=20)?&b:&c)=30;`

Comment: You could consider [GCC extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters in C this expression

```
a<=20?b=30:c=30
```

is equivalent to

```
( a<=20?b=30:c ) = 30
```

and the compiler will issue an error because the left operand of the assignment is not lvalue.

You have to write

```
a <= 20 ? b = 30 : ( c = 30 )
```

or for symmetry

```
a <= 20 ? ( b = 30 ) : ( c = 30 )
```

What you mean is the following

*( a <= 20 ? &b : &c ) = 30;

It is a trick of getting a reference to an object in the C meaning that is indirectly through a pointer to an object. The pointer itself is rvalue but dereferencing it you get lvalue of the pointed object.

In C++ you could write simply

```
( a <= 20 ? b : c ) = 30;
```

because in this case the operator returns lvalue.

There is a difference between C and C++ in the definition of the grammar of the conditional operator.

In C it is defined like (6.5.15 Conditional operator)

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

while in C++ (C++ 14, 5.16 Conditional operator)

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

So in C++ the original expression that is not compiled by the C compiler is valid

```
a <= 20 ? b = 30 : c = 30
```

Comment: are you sure about the precedence?

Comment: @bolov Yes, I am sure.

Comment: you are right, I was thinking in C++ mode. Didn't know of the difference to C here.

Answer (score 5):

supposing *a* and *b* are numbers of the same type, just do

```
*((a <= 20) ? &b : &c) = 30;
```

getting *a* and *b* address it is needed to dereference (the '*') to have a *lvalue*

from @Vrintle remark note you can also do in C++

```
((a<=20)?b:c)=30;
```

the compiler knows the form is a *lvalue* so the value of *b* and *c* are not used but their reference

> It seems like one of the parenthesis is missing there, but I don't know where.

in `((a<=20)?&b:&c)=30);` the last ')' does not have corresponding '('

Comment: Wouldn't just `(a<=20?b:c)=30;` be fine?

Comment: @Vrintle no because you get the value of *b* or *c*, so is like to write `10=20`, a *lvalue* is required

Comment: Seems okay. But, I ran it on [TIO](https://tio.run/##TYy9DoMwDIR3nsKiC0hU4mdLk/IsiYlQpBJQcCbEs6d2py73@c724XE8V8RSHiHiJy8edNhPSt5u7ypEgs2G2LRwVQBiLRgY@g4ck4GCF@8aq83Yz05ha6ZfctKiFO6ZQGt@Y6m7WuD@ZpTL5CmnKD13KV8), [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/6yykqi) and it gave no errors. Why so?

Comment: @Vrintle I edited my answer, thank you for the remark, I just wakeup ;-)

Comment: @Vrintle finaly I read again wrong because your form was not in OP question, so I edited again ...

Comment: +one for your assistance. I didn't knew that in C/C++, we can do the way you did :)

Comment: @Vrintle: It gave no errors on TIO or cpp.sh because you compiled it as C++, and the rules in C++ are different. In C, `(a <= 20 ? b : c)` is not an lvalue, so it cannot be the left operand of an assignment (in the absence of a compiler extension to the language). Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, the lvalues `b` and `c` are converted to values in the `? :` expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Oh yes, you're right, that's what bruno was saying me. Didn't noticed the [c] tag earlier :P